# Django not displaying images which are in media folder?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-media

In my django project I just want to plot some image which are there in my media folder. Eventhough the path I am seding to my frontend exists and I have verified multiple times if the path is correct. The images wont display and the error is
`Not Found: /home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/section_1_2.png [07/May/2023 16:15:52] "GET /home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/section_1_2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2490`

I have checked this same path with os.path.exists() and I get True as output but for some reason the images wont get displayed in the front end

## SETTINGS.PY

```
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    STATUSFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    )
```

## URLS.PY

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', views.get_logfile_path, name = "input_log_file"),
        path('output/', views.graphs, name= 'graphs')
    ]
```

output/ is where I am displaying the images

## VIEWS.py

```
    for image in sec_1_image_names:
        sec_1_image_paths.append(os.path.join(output_plots,image))
 
    # Sample outputpf sec_1_image_paths 
    # ['/home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/section_1_4.png']
    return render(request, 'output.html', {'image_urls':sec_1_image_paths})
```

## OUTPUT.HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Image View</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Images:</h1>
        {% for url in image_urls %}
          <img src="{{ url }}" />
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

## ERROR

```
    "GET /home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/section_1_1.pn HTTP/1.1"   404 2490
```

Comment: Your url should be `/media/section_1_1.png` as you have set your MEDIA_URL to `/media/`, meaning that any request to `/media/<path>` URL will lead to `/home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/<path>` directory

Comment: I did try this but it did not work for me. I also did os.path.exists() for my image paths and I get True for os.path.exists(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,image)) but false for os.path.exists(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL,image))

Comment: what is `sec_1_image_names`? show more view code.

Comment: @fragger that's because `os.path.exists(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL,image))` results in `/media/image` which is not valid path (because it's an absolute path in unix systems), yet it should not be valid, because it's path of your url.

Comment: @IvanStarostin That's the name of my images. It looks like this ['section_1_4.png','section_1_3.png']

Comment: @sudden_appearance Yeah, you're right but when I use `MEDIA_ROOT` I get the complete path ie. `/home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/section_1_1.png` which exists but my HTML is not able to find it

Comment: Your html is within your browser client. Any links there should be URL's not file paths. Imagine another user on other PC loads your html. He does not have that file. He makes HTTP requests to `/media/<image>` and your server returns it to him from servers disk path which is `/home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/<image>`

Comment: @sudden_appearance try to hit http://localhost:127.0.0.1/home/harish/Desktop/project/visual/media/section_1_1.pn  in your browser and see if image is getting displayed there or not!